# What typeclasses need to be defined for a Yesod path?

Tags: haskell, yesod

In my application, my data model has several different instances of using an Integer or a String for some identifier.  For safety, I've gone ahead and wrapped those identifiers into newtype declarations like so:

```
newtype DocId = DocId Integer
newtype GroupName = GroupName String
newtype UserName = UserName String
```

When I'm setting up my Yesod paths, I'm discovering that I have to create at least three instances for each of these, and the instances are almost always identical

```
instance Read DocId where
    readsPrec prec val = case reads val of
        (i, ""):_ -> [(DocId i, "")]
        [] -> []

instance B.ToMarkup DocId where
    toMarkup (DocId val) = B.toMarkup val

instance PathPiece DocId where
    toPathPiece (DocId i) = T.pack $ show i
    fromPathPiece s =
        case reads $ T.unpack s of
            (i, ""):_ -> Just i
            [] -> Nothing
```

This text, over and over again.

What do I really need to set up in order to both render my data type in URLs (like @{ViewDocument docId}) and be able to parse those URLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you turn on `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, then you can just add `deriving PathPiece` under each new datatype, or `deriving instance PathPiece DocId` if you can't derive directly on the datatype.

You will need Read, Show, and PathPiece instances for every datatype that is to be part of a route.

Comment: Actually, I can't do that because of the strict separation I make in my application.  The place where I declare most of my data types is in a library that is unaware of Yesod at all.

Comment: You can equivalently use standalone deriving: `deriving instance PathPiece DocId`. But is it really true that you can't import `Web.PathPieces` at the declaration site of your types? I'd personally much prefer doing that to creating orphan instances.

Comment: Orphan instances are actually starting to annoy me pretty badly.  But my core library represents a "headless" implementation of the application and doesn't even have a dependency on any web tools.  The application that I deploy imports both my core library and Yesod.  Standalone deriving works great, though.  I had no idea that could be done.  Kinda like I have no idea how to define a datatype that can be derive.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some trial and error (i.e., removing features and seeing what breaks) it looks like in order for a data type to be part of a Yesod path, it needs three typeclasses to be defined:

- Read
- Show
- PathPiece

My ToMarkup declaration above applies to how I display my data types in the Html (Hamlet, Blaze, whatever, but in my case Hamlet).  It is therefore not necessary if I'm only going to put the data type into a URL.