# Automatically deriving PathPiece

Tags: haskell, yesod

In my Yesod web-application I have following data type:

```
data SensorType = TemperatureSensor | HumiditySensor deriving (Eq, Show, Read, PathPiece, PersistField)
```

I enable `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`

The answer about automatically deriving `PathPiece`:

[What typeclasses need to be defined for a Yesod path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751415/what-typeclasses-need-to-be-defined-for-a-yesod-path)

But I get ghc-error:

```
Can't make a derived instance of `PathPiece SensorType
  `PathPiece' is not a derivable class
```

Is it possible automatically derive `PathPiece`? What I do wrong?

For `PersistField` exists `derivePersistField`. What about `PathPiece`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to automatically create an instance for PathPiece because toPathPiece should output a path with a meaning corresponding to your application. There is no way that the compiler can read your mind. Is TemperatureSensor going to be /tmpSensor or /tmprSnsr or /temperatureSensor ?

Comment: toPathPiece TemperatureSensor should be (in my undestanding) default show. Path looks like `/TemperatureSensor`, because deriving Show instance map TemperatureSensor to `"TemperatureSensor"`. Similarly, for Read instance.

Comment: Right, but the choice to make TemperatureSensor map to the path "TemperatureSensor" is a *design* decision.

Answer (score 3):

`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, as its name implies, is only useful for deriving instances for `newtype`s. It works by lifting instances of the underlying type over the newtype wrapper.

Your type is not a `newtype` so there is no `PathPiece` instance to lift.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible automatically derive `PathPiece` for `data`s?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like that's possible, based on the [path-pieces package](https://github.com/yesodweb/path-pieces) not doing anything like that or any code I can find [on Github](https://github.com/search?l=haskell&p=1&q=instance+PathPiece&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93). I would implement the `PathPiece` typeclass like this (using `tshow` and `readMay` from classy prelude):

```
instance PathPiece SensorType where
    toPathPiece = tshow
    fromPathPiece = readMay
```